# shared_ptr of a templated type enclosing it

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, std-pair

Is it possible to have `shared_ptr` pointing to a templated type enclosing it? For example,

```
pair<shared_ptr<ThisPairType>, int>
```

How should this be defined?

Comment: The best I could think of is `struct ThisPairType : std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ThisPairType>, int> {};` Which is not quite what you want, but close.

Comment: You'd be better off writing a custom struct. Giving the fields meaningful names instead of `first` and `second` is reason enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to write what you want directly because the *name* of the type is not yet complete at the point you want to use it. You can't even get around this with a `typedef` because it is not possible to forward declare typedefs.

I recommend simply writing a struct:

```
struct Recursive { std::shared_ptr<Recursive> first; int second; };
```

Or inheriting from `pair` as recommended by [igor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) comment:

> The best I could think of is `struct ThisPairType : std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ThisPairType>, int> {};` Which is not quite what you want, but close.

Comment: You were so close to linking the question itself... But do note that comments are volatile, and you should copy it if you want to refer to it.